# How do I make sure that customer file uploads are secure when using the file upload custom option?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a request for customers to be able to submit drawing and image files via a custom option in Magento 1.7.0.2. I have the upload working I am just not sure if it is the most secure. It seemed to easy so naturally I'm a little paranoid. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `getimagesize()`. It will return zeros for size on non-images. Details you can find [here](http://www.php.net/getimagesize).